# how to access my yahoo or gmail account in outlook (c#)?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, add-in, mapi

I have 3 data files:

1. Outlook data file (is empty)
2. Gmail data file (from my gmail pop3)
3. Yahoo data file (from my yahoo imap)

I can access the Outlook data file inbox (which is always empty, I don't know how to automatically move from my google and yahoo account to my outlook data file) with 
this code:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.
     ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
     (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I make my gmail and yahoo account automatically move to my outlook data file?
2. How to code to access my inbox in my gmail and yahoo account?

I have tried this function to make return to my MAPIFolder:

```
public Outlook.MAPIFolder GetInbox(string userName)
    {
        Outlook.Application oOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.Recipient oRep = oNs.CreateRecipient(userName);
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        return inbox;
    }
```

But it didn't work. help me pleaseee..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your first question, would you like to join all the data files into the main outlook data file?

About your second question, Outlook data files are represented by stores in the API, and if you call GetDefaultFolder on the Session object, you'll always end up with getting the default store's default folder (Inbox of your Outlook data file).

You can list all the store files and use GetDefaultFolder on them to retrieve the inbox folders for each store/data file:

```
Outlook.Stores stores = this.Appliction.Session.Stores;
foreach( Store store in stores )
{
   Outlook.Folder inboxOfStore = store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

   //Do stuff with your inbox folder.. Check store properties for infomation on which data file this store represents
}
```

See documentation for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176405%28v=office.12%29.aspx